In Next.JS 14 I am generating static generation. But Css not working
I am able to generate static html files from Next.js but the issue is that after static generation the CSS are not working. But in development all css were working fine.
I am using typescript also (.tsx)

There are multiple reasons why this is happening:

Check CSS Import Method
Inspect the Generated HTML and CSS Files: you must check that all the imports are correct... you can also check by opening the static html file in browser
Hosting Configuration: whatever platform you are using for hosting check their specific settings for serving static assets


How to check CSS import method?

What I am trying to say here is that the path you are importing your css file from should be correct sometimes there's an extra dot or one less dot in the path causing the error..
